# ZF: How to add default prefix path to form elements so I don't have to set it everytime?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there any way to do this so that I don't always have to add a prefix path before adding a custom decorator to an element?  Thx!

Comment: what do you mean by default prefix path? can you given an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your code (I'd extend all your forms from a base form class where you can put this into the construct).

```
$this->addPrefixPath('My_Form_Element', 'My/Form/Element', 'ELEMENT');
```